# Allow users to edit a Single page on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, edit

i manage my company website which runs WordPress. There are several chapters across the USA. I have pages setup for them so that people can view our chapters content. I was wondering, instead of them emailing me the changes they want. Is there a way where i can allow the users to only be able to edit a single page, without giving them access to the entire WordPress admin page/ website.
I would be willing to pay for a commercial plug if this option exists. Thanks for reading this.

Comment: [have you even googled?](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities)

Answer (score 1):

There are Various Free / Paid Solution will be available for this based on your Model You can Choose any one of the following or there could be many other ways to get this done these are some of the way

1. You Can make them Editor and The Owner of the Chapter which they blong so in this way they will not have any rights to Edit other Chapters they will be only able to edit the Chapters which they own.To restrict other access in this case you can use plugin like [User Role Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) and many other available at Wordpress repo.
2. You can also customize plugin like [WP User Frontend](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-user-frontend/) to achieve the front end edit possible.
3. A Complete Custom Solution where use need not to login they simply submit the Changes which will be logged as article draft and you can later review and approve.

i think there will be much more way but it will be completely based on your applications nature so hope this helps to you.